# Selenium Issue: Select.deselectAll() causing iframe issues

Tags: java, iframe, selenium, multi-select

I'm testing a site using the Selenium Browser Automation framework.  During testing I switch to a specific frame, let's call it "frame_1".  Later, I use the deselectAll() method in the Select class.  Shortly after that, I get a StaleElementReferenceException, IE a frame reference problem whereby "frame_1" is no longer targeted.

However, if I comment out the deselectAll() on the relevant multiselect box things work as usual (except the multiselect isn't cleared, of course).

Since I am manipulating the same elements whether I call the deselectAll() method or not, and I only get the frame reference exceptions when I call deselectAll() I'm suspicious that this method call has an effect on which frame is targeted, or etc...

Is this expected behavior and/or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue was triggered before the deselectAll() call.  First, I created a Select object, second some javascript code removed an item from that select list.  At this point the Select object was stale and therefore the deselectAll() call failed (and not some other manipulation after that.)